# Google Contacts not Syncing to Phone

Tags: contacts, sync, google

Although everything else is syncing from my Google account to my phone, my Google Contacts won't sync!  I have all of my friends' and family member's numbers in my Google Contacts.  Any ideas as to why everything but my Contacts would sync??

Comment: Maybe the SyncML library is missing. Please add your phone brand and model so we can assist you further.

Comment: http://www.droidforums.net/threads/when-does-google-sync-contacts.14278/

Answer (score 0):

Head to your settings and find the personal account/sync option and then select google. Tap on the account in question and then if your calendar sync is off, tap it to enable it.